# How to use siunitx with non numerical values?

Tags: formatting, siunitx

I understand that something like `\SI{5}{\meter\per\second}` defines a certain space between the number (5) and units (m/s). What should I use if instead of a numerical quantity I want a variable: R m/s? `\SI{R}{\meter\per\second}` fails because it expect a number in first parameter, and `R \si{\meter\per\second}` or `$R$ \si{\meter\per\second}` show different space.

Which is the correct use?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r}
\SI{5}{\meter\per\second}\\
$R$ \si{\meter\per\second}\\
R \si{\meter\per\second}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you want that? Combining variables with units makes the variables dependent on the unit system and thereby essentially meaningless, from a physics point of view. I suggest you rather use `$R\cdot u$, where $u$ is \SI{1}{\meter\per\second}`.

Comment: May be the word variables is not correct in this case. I want to say something like 'a car goes at A m/s and the road has B Km ...' (not so easy problems and with a better style in my language). What should be the word in English?

Comment: No no, variable is quite the right word. My point is that it's _not physically meaningful_ to say something like 'a car goes at A m/s and the road has B km ...'. Just say 'a car goes at speed v and the road has length l': v and l are physical quantities independent of any particular choice of units. Only when you're finally giving numerical values for these quantities it makes sense to say stuff like 'let now v = 37 m/s', or 'values of l in km: {60, 70, 89, 130}'. — Anyway, that's not a typesetting concern and therefore doesn't belong to this site, I just wanted to say it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: This is useful when using scaling variables, e.g., 25α dB, where α is the scaling variable.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Units are just constants of a certain physical dimension, so there is no reason to forbid what the OP wants, nor is there a reason to introduce additional names for units, like you suggest in you first comment $u=$m/s. "Why would you want that?" Say you plot data in a coordinate system and label the horizontal axis with a velocity $v$, then all the ticks along the axis should carry units like 0m/s, 5m/s, 10m/s, etc. Most people would rather just label the ticks with numbers 0,5,10 etc. but then the label $v$ would be wrong. The correct label would be $v$/(m/s). Or $v$s/m

Comment: @Michael of course you don't in practice want to repeat the units written out for all the axis ticks, nor for all the numbers in a table column. But still, that's _conceptually_ the right thing. It doesn't generally make sense to plot quantities with different units in a single diagram; when doing that you should always e.g. add an extra axis on the right border, with the correct unit. So, I'd consider the /(m/s) style more as a _shortcut notation_ of ticks with 0m/s, 5m/s, 10m/s labels. It's merely a bonus that the shortcut also can be read as “we plot the dimensionless quantity /(m/s)”.

Comment: Your comment is somewhat misleading. It's _not_ conceptually wrong to divide or multiply a variable by a constant as in v/(m/s). In fact, in your earlier comment when you say "l in km", that's _conceptually_ the same as saying l/km.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As others have commented, this is partly a style question. In terms of non-numerical input, you've got a couple of choices. You could add `R` as a 'symbol' to those that `siunitx` knows, but that will not always print in math mode. So I'd prefer the approach of turning off the number parser:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI[parse-numbers = false]{R}{\metre\per\second}
\end{document}
```

As egreg points out, to get italic output you'll need to set the `math-rm` option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI[number-math-rm = \mathnormal, parse-numbers = false]{R}{\metre\per\second}
\end{document}
```

Turning off the parser forces math mode, but retains font control and also consistent spacing (so if you alter the setting for `number-unit-separator` it will be updated).

Comment: Aren't we talking about `\SI[math-rm = \ensuremath, parse-numbers = false]{R}{\metre\per\second}` here instead?

Comment: The option for `\SI` should be `math-rm`, not `mathrm` (I C&P-ed this snippet and got an error). I attempted to fix the typo, but TeX.SX said "Edits must be at least 6 characters"...

Comment: @Merzong Indeed: fixed (I can do such edits) :-)

Comment: `math-rm=\mathnormal` will also cause the units to be set in italic! Instead use `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\mathnormal{R}}{\metre\per\second}`.

Comment: @ElmarPeise So it would: I meant `number-math-rm`

Comment: This is also very helpful if one wants to write bit numbers with the base of 2 and any exponent, like `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{2^5}{\bit}`.

Answer (score 12):

I think you are raising two questions: First, how to set the spacing between the "R" and its unit (m/s) and second, whether to typeset the "R" in upright or italic shape.

Regarding the former: I believe what `siunitx` does in the `\SI` macro is to insert a `thinspace` width between the quantity and its unit; one can generate this spacing manually with the `\,` command. Regarding the latter question: I believe it is (near-)universal practice to typeset variables in italic shape. Hence, I'd recommend you use the following command:

```
$R$\,\si{meter\per\second}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\varSI}{O{}}{\SI[math-rm=\mathnormal,parse-numbers=false,#1]}

\varSI{R}{\meter\per\second}
\varSI[math-rm=\mathbf]{R}{\meter\per\second}
```

Comment: I'd use `\NewDocumentCommand` here: it makes the new macro protected and also not 'long' (of course, `\newcommand*` would also do the later).

Comment: @JosephWright I forgot that **siunitx** loads **xparse**. However the command is robust anyway, since it uses `\newcommand` with an optional argument.

Comment: (Normally) A command taking an optional argument is not robust, as it uses `\futurelet` internally and so can't be `\edef`ed.

Comment: @JosephWright It used to be so years ago; see LaTeX News of December 1995.

Comment: @egreg: Your suggestion of a `NewDocumentCommand` (or `newcommand`) which just declares some portion of a longer command it's new to me. Interesting! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested above, you can declare the following:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\varSI{omm}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}%
  {\SI{#2}{#3}}%
  {$#1$\,$=$\,\SI{#2}{#3}}%
}
```

The physical quantity comes as the optional argument and is displayed (if specified) in math mode, whereas the numerical value and the unit come as mandatory arguments. Hence, use wherever in the text `\varSI[Quantity]{Value}{Unit with siunitx}` or `\varSI{Value}{Unit with siunitx}`

For example, you can use either `\varSI[E_K]{3}{\electronvolt}` to display E<sub>K</sub> = 3 eV and only `\varSI{3}{\electronvolt}` to write 3 eV depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do for instance is to introduce the `\si` part into the mathmode part:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r}
\SI{5}{\meter\per\second}\\
$R\,\si{\meter\per\second}$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Then you have control of the spacing and you can choose a different spacing than `\,` if you like.