# Italicizing Variables in SI unit commands

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

As many other answers have elucidated, the correct way to typeset SI units is with the `SI` command from `siunitx`. However, if the value being described is a variable (for example, *x* metres), doing

```
$\SI[parse-numbers=false]{x}{\m}$
```

in math mode will produce "x m" rather than the correct "*x* m", with an italicized *x*.

I've attempted to rectify this through toying with the settings of `sisetup` as per the CTAN documentation for `siunitx`, but so far I can't find anything to enable this behavior.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: `$\SI[number-math-rm = \mathnormal,parse-numbers=false]{x}{\m}$`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30823/121799.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `\si` from the same package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
Consider as square with a width of $x\,\si{\m}$.
\end{document}
```

The `\,` is for inserting a small space between *x* and m.

[image]